# Books to learn Ray Tracing

Tags: raytracing, physically-based, directx11

Recently I have developed and interest in Ray Tracing and like most computer graphics tutorials online there is nothing regarding implementation for a beginner like myself.

So far I have only done real time rendering (DirectX), however I understand the basics of Ray Tracing but I want to buy a book before proceeding any further. I've taken a look at [Physically Based Rendering: From Theory to Implementation](http://www.pbrt.org/) (I want to learn Ray Tracing with a Physically Based Approach so I thought this would be great) but I don't think it's good for a beginner since there's not much emphasis on the code.

When I was learning DirectX 11 everyone recommended Frank Luna's **[Introduction to 3D Game Programming](http://www.d3dcoder.net/d3d11.htm)**, which was great since it covered all the basics and also a few advanced topics like SSAO with an approach a beginner could understand. Is there something like this for Ray Tracing?

Comment: Physically Based Rendering: From Theory to Implementation has loads of code in it. It explains a lot line by line. You also have the pbrt implementation on Github too. It's a great book.

Comment: I've only been able to read sample chapters but based on what you've said I might buy this book.

Comment: PBRT is written with a _[literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming)_ approach, which means that the book not only explains the whole theory but also the entire implementation almost line by line.


It is an amazing book and well worth a read if you're interested in the topic. Make sure to get the newly released 3rd edition ;)

Comment: @tizian As a beginner who has never written a single ray tracer before should I buy it? I plan to do the scratchapixel tutorials online but once I'm done with that should I buy the book?

Comment: @ArjanSingh PBRT might be better suited if you already have some prior knowledge about ray tracing and want to make the jump to state-of-the-art physically-based rendering.

I heard many great things about Peter Shirley's "minibook" series mentioned in another answer here already; this might be a good place to start instead.

Comment: @ArjanSingh although book recommendation questions are off topic here on main, you could ask about it in [chat].

Answer (score 5):

For an introduction, you can give a look at: [Ray Tracing from the Ground Up](http://www.raytracegroundup.com/) (Amazon link [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812728)).

[image: Cover]

It starts really from the basics, and provides simple implementations for the concepts that are gradually introduced.

Comment: This book is very great. It's written in a very pleasant way and doesn't scare with advanced maths very early on.

Answer (score 3):

Not a book, but here's an online write-up about the basics of Monte Carlo path tracing:
[Path Tracing – Getting Started With Diffuse and Emissive | The blog at the bottom of the sea](http://blog.demofox.org/2016/09/21/path-tracing-getting-started-with-diffuse-and-emissive/)

I've also heard good things a out Peter Shirley's books. In particular "Ray Tracing in one Weekend"
[Ray Tracing in One Weekend (Ray Tracing Minibooks Book 1) Kindle Edition | amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B5AODD8)